# Why does the regular expression not return the data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have this string:

```js
const sab = `{{Animanqa/Başlıq
|başlıq          = Külək güclənir
|şəkil           = Kaze Tachinu poster.jpg
|şəkilölçü       = 
|şəkilizah       = 
|janradı         = 風立ちぬ <br/>Kaze Tachinu
|janradıt        = 
|janr            = [[Dram filmi|dram]]<br/>[[Tarixi film|tarixi]]<br/>[[Bioqrafik film|bioqrafik]]
}}
{{Animanqa/Film
|başlıq          = 
|başlıq_small    = 
|director        = [[Hayao Miyazaki]]
|writer          = [[Hayao Miyazaki]] <br/>[[Tatsuo Hori]] <br/>"Kaze Tachinu"
|producer        = [[Toşio Suzuki]]
|music           = [[Co Hisayşi]] 
|studio          = [[Studio Ghibli]]
|licensor        = 
|release_date    = [[2013]]
|runtime = 126 dəqiqə
}}
{{Animanqa/Son}}`
```

And I'm tryna get all the data between `{{Animanqa/Başlıq` and `}}` (just before `{{Animanqa/Film`).

Here you go my current RegExp code:

```
console.log (sab.match (/((^{{Animanqa\/Başlıq)((.*|\n))*)}}\n{{Animanqa\/(.*)/gm))
```

So, this code works but with a little problem: it takes the entire data until `{{Animanqa/Son}}`. But when I change the inner side of brackets near `/gm` (e.g. to `(Film)/gm`, the emulator stops respondin'. What can I do?

Comment: when I try to run it online, I get this message `Catastrophic backtracking has been detected and the execution of your expression has been halted.`, which is as bad as it sounds :) . More on this here :https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Comment: @Pac0, I also tried to run the code online on Wandbox and the action was killed. (Edit: thanks for the source, I'm gonna read it and try again)

Comment: problem is basically too many possible matches with all the `*`. I'd suggest reading the example on the link I provded, and I remember they also provide some advice on how to rewrite. In essence, try to restrict the matching possibilities.

Comment: Instead of `((.*|\n))*` just use `.*` and add the `s` flag so that `.` matches newlines.

Comment: You can even run the online debugger and see the matching engine in works step by step, by the way. Linnk under the error message I quoted.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks much, I tried it and worked!

Comment: sorry, my comment was not clear, I'm talking about the debugger here : https://regex101.com/ (try to run with problematic regex). And you're welcome!